# Network IO bottleneck in multithreading app when querying the same server

Tags: c#, multithreading

Title pretty much says it all.is this a TCP/IP issue?

C#, I have 10 threads going off simultaneously using a thread timer and Join () method. some or all of the threads may query the same server at the sametime (I am querying directories on the remote servers using EnumerateDirectories to see if the directory exists). The check itself is quick and simple yet if I query them all at once it take much longer for the threads to exit then if I simply do them one by one in a single thread.

Is this a result of the methods i am using or a result of network IO block?

I use 10 long running TPl Tasks and they all call this code at some point. Now the threads may not all query the same server, but at times they do and the below code blocks and take forever to complete.

Code:

```
    String shareStatus = "NOT ACTIVE";
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate () {
        String errorString = "";
        try
        {
            List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(strLink));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorString = e.Message;
        }

        if (errorString == "" || errorString.Contains("is denied") == true)
            shareStatus = "ACTIVE";
    }));
    t.Start();
    bool completed = t.Join(10000);
    if (!completed)
        t.Abort();
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share? It may help in illustrating the issue.

Comment: Show your query code

Comment: However the rule of thumb, is if you are going to do IO workloads, use `async` and `await` pattern, if you want to do things in parallel, the `ActionBlocks` are a good choice as they are designed with this in mind. This will allow IO to be IO, and not have to wait around blocking threads and using resources waiting for IO completion ports

Comment: I added the code to my original post.